# Multi type search with independent filters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-2, tire

I have a separate index for each account, in which the mappings for each model (user and comments - just an example, actual app has many models) are specified.

```
include Tire::Model::Search

Tire.index('account_1') do
  create(
    :mappings => {
      :user => {
        :properties => {
          :name => { :type => :string, :boost => 10 },
          :company_name => { :type => :string, :boost => 5 },
          :blocked => { :type => :boolean, :include_in_all => false }
        }
      },
      :comments => {
        :properties => {
          :description => { :type => :string, :boost => 5 }
        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

How do I add a filter in my search query such that, only users with blocked => true are returned in search results. **This should not affect the search results of comments type.**
Is this possible? Is there any filter in elasticsearch to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer...

You can use an or combo of not-exists and term filter...

```
    search_key = 'test'
    Tire.search [account_1] do
      query do
        filtered do
            query { string search_key }
            filter :or, { :not => { :exists => { :field => :blocked } } },
                        { :term => { :blocked => true } }
        end
      end
    end
```